# Only scale image if above certain dimensions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an image loader in which the user uploads their own image and I was wondering how to scale the image only if the width and height exceed a certain size? This is so that, for example, a 200 x 200 image won't be scaled but a 2000 x 2000 image will be.

```
function selectedFile(e:Event):void{
    browseImage.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeLoadImage);
    browseImage.load();
    browseImage.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectedFile);
}

function completeLoadImage(e:Event):void{

imageLoader.loadBytes(e.target.data);
imageLayer.addChild(imageLoader);
if (imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.width > 250 && imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.height > 250)
{
    imageLoader.scaleX = imageLoader.scaleY = 0.2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Loader.contentLoaderInfo`.

```
const MIN_HEIGHT_FOR_SCALING:Number = 1000;
const MIN_WIDTH_FOR_SCALING:Number = 1000;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
    if (loader.contentLoaderInfo.height > MIN_HEIGHT_FOR_SCALING && loader.contentLoaderInfo.width > MIN_WIDTH_FOR_SCALING) {
        loader.scaleX = loader.scaleY = .2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get `Error #2099: The loading object is not sufficiently loaded to provide this information.`

Comment: My mistake. I generally don't use `Loader` for images (I generally use Flex). Listen for `loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, handler)` instead.

Comment: I've updated the original post with what I have. I was getting `Error #1069: Property data not found on flash.display.LoaderInfo and there is no default value.`